# What is `postfix/smtps/smtpd` in my log file?

Tags: postfix, mail, smtp

I know that postfix/smtpd is for incoming mails, smtp for outgoing  mails. But I do see in my logfile several entries with `postfix/smtps/smtpd`. What is this for?

```
Feb 22 10:57:55 mx postfix/smtps/smtpd[XXXX]: lost connection after EHLO from XXXX[XXXX]
Feb 22 10:57:55 mx postfix/smtps/smtpd[XXXX]: disconnect from XXXX[XXXX] ehlo=1 commands=1
Feb 22 11:07:27 mx postfix/smtps/smtpd[XXXX]: warning: hostname XXXX does not resolve to address XXXX
Feb 22 11:07:27 mx postfix/smtps/smtpd[XXXX]: connect from unknown[XXXX]
Feb 22 11:07:30 mx postfix/smtps/smtpd[XXXX]: SSL_accept error from unknown[XXXX]: lost connection
Feb 22 11:07:30 mx postfix/smtps/smtpd[XXXX]: lost connection after CONNECT from unknown[XXXX]
Feb 22 11:07:30 mx postfix/smtps/smtpd[XXXX]: disconnect from unknown[XXXX] commands=0/0
Feb 22 11:18:22 mx postfix/smtps/smtpd[XXXX]: SSL_accept error from unknown[XXXX]: -1
Feb 22 11:18:22 mx postfix/smtps/smtpd[XXXX]: warning: TLS library problem: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number:../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:354:
Feb 22 11:18:22 mx postfix/smtps/smtpd[XXXX]: lost connection after CONNECT from unknown[XXXX]
Feb 22 11:18:22 mx postfix/smtps/smtpd[XXXX]: disconnect from unknown[XXXX] commands=0/0
Feb 22 11:53:13 mx postfix/smtps/smtpd[XXXX]: connect from unknown[XXXX]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

postfix/smtps/smtpd is the combination of:

- postfix/smtps handles encrypted incoming mail connections used for secure email submission.
- postfix/smtpd handles unencrypted incoming mail connections used for receiving emails from other servers.

You'll see this daemon in your logs for all incoming mail activities which include successful connections, disconnections, errors, EHLO commands, etc.

In your log example:

- The first two lines refer to a successful connection, EHLO command exchange, and disconnection from an unknown sender which involves smtpd for receiving the email.
- The remaining lines all involve unsuccessful connection attempts from unknown senders with SSL/TLS errors. These fall under smtp**s** (for handling **s**ecure connections) but likely involve smtpd (for receiving email) as well.

Answer (score -1):

You're maybe familiar with the difference between `http://` and `https://` as the protocol for HTTP requests. `https://` is used for HTTP connections that are encrypted with TLS (in earlier days, with SSL).

In a similar fashion, you can put TLS "on top" of SMTP. That's then called [SMTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTPS). The log entries you're seeing are connected to that. Another indication is that some relevant keywords pop up in the log messages, like "SSL_accept" or "TLS library problem".